# $\left\{x\in H: 2\leq \|x\|\leq 5\right\}$ is compact?

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

In a Hilbert space $H$ of dimention infinite, $A=\left\{x\in H:2\leq \|x\|\leq 5\right\}$ is compact? (totally bounded and complete)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The general proof in a normed space can be done using [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma).

In Hilberst spaces, you can use an easier proof as follows: Take $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots v_n, \cdots \}$ to be an o.n.b. Then considen $u_n=2v_n$. $||u_n||=2$ but $||u_n-u_m||^2=4+4=8$ (Check).

So, $u_n$ can't have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I think this is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not compact. Consider the points
$$
A_1=(2,\cdots), A_2=(1,1,\cdots ), A_3=(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cdots)
$$
where for $A_{n}$, each coordinate in $1\cdots n$ dimension has value $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$ and all other coordinates' value is $0$. Then we have:
$$
|A_{n}|=2, \forall n
$$
as well as
$$
A_{n}\rightarrow 0
$$
assume $A_{n}$ is convergent.

If the set you described is compact, then $A_{n}$ must have a convergent subsequence. But this does not hold since $|0|=0$. Here I am assuming $H\cong l^{2}$.

Comment: Actually $A_n$ does not converges to $0$ in $\ell^2$ norm.

Comment: If $A_{n}$ does converge, then it must converge to $0$. But its norm does not converge, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: @John: By $A_n \rightarrow 0$ I think he means convergence in $l_{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: No, John is right that I cannot give $H$ two norms in the same time. But here since I assume the set is compact, $A_{n}$ must have a subsequence converge to something. Then by elementary arguments it must converge to $0$ coordinate wise. But this then contradicts.